# Store input's value as a variable to used in an equation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm putting data from a mysql db and place it within a hidden input field. From there I want to store the value of the input field as a javascript variable so that I may run an equation on it.

The following is an example the code:

```
<input type="text" name="hiddenValue" value="<?php include('select.php'); ?>">

var inputValue = $("#hiddenValue").val();

var startValue = ((inputValue - totalCost) / totalCost ) * 100;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: and the output from `select.php` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set an `id` attribute to your input :

`<input type="text" id="hiddenValue" name="hiddenValue" value="<?php include('select.php'); ?>">`

`$("#hiddenValue").val();` selected the element that id=hiddenValue

Comment: Clearly I am tired. Took me a while to see that. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='hiddenValue']").val();
```

You are using the `id` selector `#` and in this case, it does not exist.